# MouseMove event is called even when cursor is outside of canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I don`t know if something is wrong with my code or WPF, but here is the problem: I want to create a small program, where you can draw with your cursor in the canvas.
I have a simple WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="475" Width="544">
<Grid>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100px"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height ="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100px"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Name="imageCanvas" MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave" Background="LightGray" 
                      MouseDown="StackPan_MouseDown" MouseUp="StackPan_MouseUp" MouseMove="StackPan_MouseMove">

        </Canvas>        
</Grid>
```

Here is the background code:

```
   private void StackPan_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = true;
    }

    private void StackPan_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
    }

    private void StackPan_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw)
        {
            var pos = Mouse.GetPosition(imageCanvas);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle()
                    {
                        Width = 10,
                        Height = 10,
                        Fill = Brushes.Red,
                    };
            Canvas.SetTop(rec, pos.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rec, pos.X);
            imageCanvas.Children.Add(rec);
        }

    }
```

And what can I do is the following:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7moq4p8f8f409b3/wpf_canvas.png

Why does StackPan_MouseMove called when the cursor is outside of canvas?

Here is the executable file, where you can notice this behavore:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye1w2j9chld2oif/WpfApplication1.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the Canvas inside a Border control and setting the `Border` control's [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) property to `true`.

```
<Border ClipToBounds="true" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Canvas Name="imageCanvas" MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave" Background="LightGray" 
            MouseDown="StackPan_MouseDown" MouseUp="StackPan_MouseUp" MouseMove="StackPan_MouseMove">
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

On a slightly different note, it seems that an [InkPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkpresenter.aspx)/[InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx) may be a more suitable control for what you're trying to do, unless you're avoiding them for specific reasons.

Comment: Adding border helped to solve the issue, thanks much.
I tried to use MouseLeave event, but the problem is MouseEnter is called too, when cursor is ouside of canvas.

Comment: You're welcome :) I removed the MouseLeave part after I saw your XAML already included it.

Answer (score 1):

You get MouseMove events by the Rectangle children of the Canvas.

Although you should better use an InkPresenter or an InkCanvas (as user keyboardP has said) you may simply make the Rectangles invisible to hit testing. Then they will no longer produce any input events.

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle()
{
    Width = 10,
    Height = 10,
    Fill = Brushes.Red,
    IsHitTestVisible = false // here
};
```

Comment: Ok, then how I`m creating rectangle outside the canvas?

Comment: Thanks, Clemens. I`ll have a look to InkPresenter/IncCanvas.