# MouseMove event is called even when cursor is outside of canvas. `Border`around canvas did not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove

short discription of the to-be situation:

As soon as the mouse moves over my canvas I want an ellipse to be displayed on the canvas. The ellipse is supposed to stick to the mouse movement until the user hits the left mouse button. At the time the user hits the left mouse button, the program is expected to place the ellipse on the canvas.

Therefore I used the following xaml code:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1200">



<Grid>
    <Border ClipToBounds="true">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasss" Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="524" Height="368" MouseMove="Canvasss_MouseMove" MouseDown="Canvasss_MouseDown">

    </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And the c# code:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
         public class Item
         {
            private readonly Ellipse shape;

            public Item(Canvas canvas)
            {
                shape = new Ellipse { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Black };
                canvas.Children.Add(shape);
                SetPosition(0.0, 0.0);
            }

            public void SetPosition(double x, double y)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(shape, x);
                Canvas.SetTop(shape, y);
            }
        }

        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private readonly IList<Item> shapes;
            private Item currentMovingShape;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                shapes = new List<Item>();
                InitMovingShape();
            }

            private void InitMovingShape()
            {
                currentMovingShape = new Item(canvasss);
            }

            private void SetMovingShapePosition(MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                var pos = e.GetPosition(canvasss);
                currentMovingShape.SetPosition(pos.X - 25, pos.Y - 25);
            }

            private void Canvasss_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                var pos = e.GetPosition(canvasss);
                currentMovingShape.SetPosition(pos.X - 25, pos.Y - 25);
            }

            private void Canvasss_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                shapes.Add(currentMovingShape);
                InitMovingShape();            
            }


         }
    }
```

The problem is, that as soon as the mouse leaves the canvas, the ellipse still sticks to the mouse and it is even possible to place the ellipse outside the canvas.

First I used the code (code is from stijn: [C# - WPF - Mousemove event on canvas will overload the mouse events so click event is not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075815/c-sharp-wpf-mousemove-event-on-canvas-will-overload-the-mouse-events-so-clic)) without the `Border`around the canvas in the xaml code. Then I read it might help to place a `Border`arround the canvas ([MouseMove event is called even when cursor is outside of canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918395/mousemove-event-is-called-even-when-cursor-is-outside-of-canvas)) and implemented it to the xaml code as you can see. Unfortunetely it did not help.

Can someone help me with a solution? A code solution wold be much appreciated, since I am a total beginner in c#.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to implement [Adorners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your control. Do read about them as they will come handy to perform operations like these easily in wpf.

However, to fix your problem. You should be implementing `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to your code. Add the shape on `MouseEnter` and remove the shape on `MouseLeave` or `MouseDown`. So when the Mouse ReEnters the canvas the MouseEnter logic will kick in and will add the shape and your `MouseMove` logic will move the shape with the Mouse. Hope I am being clear here. Let me know if you are still struggling with the code.

EDIT

xaml

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvasss" Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="300" Height="300"  MouseEnter="canvasss_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="canvasss_MouseLeave"  MouseMove="Canvasss_MouseMove" MouseDown="Canvasss_MouseDown" Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly IList<Ellipse> shapes;
        private Ellipse currentMovingShape;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            shapes = new List<Ellipse>();
        }

        private void canvasss_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEllipse();
        }

        private void AddEllipse()
        {
            currentMovingShape = new Ellipse { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Black };
            currentMovingShape.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            canvasss.Children.Add(currentMovingShape);
            Canvas.SetLeft(currentMovingShape, Mouse.GetPosition(canvasss).X - 25);
            Canvas.SetTop(currentMovingShape, Mouse.GetPosition(canvasss).Y - 25);
        }

        private void canvasss_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentMovingShape != null)
            {
                canvasss.Children.Remove(currentMovingShape);
                currentMovingShape = null;
            }
        }
        private void Canvasss_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(currentMovingShape, e.GetPosition(canvasss).X - 25);
            Canvas.SetTop(currentMovingShape, e.GetPosition(canvasss).Y - 25);
        }

        private void Canvasss_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentMovingShape != null)
            {
                currentMovingShape.IsHitTestVisible = true;
                shapes.Add(currentMovingShape);
                AddEllipse();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Krishna, I have to admit, that I am not able to implement your suggestion since I don't totally understand the code I used. But I tried to implement your suggestion on a diffrent way. I used `MouseEnter`to set a flag to 1 and `MouseLeave`to set the flag to 0. When calling the `MouseMove`and `MouseDown`Event, it is checked, whether the flag is set or not before starting its routine. Unfortuantely it hardly changed anything to the result of the programm. Would appreciate it, if you could help me some more.

Comment: @Pain ok give me couple of minutes let me see if I can write some sample code. Do you understand the logical flow that I mentioned?

Comment: I do understand the logical flow. My problem is that I don't really know how to implement it with the code I used. Thanks!

Comment: @Pain Please see my edit. I dont think you need the Item class if you simply want to add an Ellipse. This code will work for you. But I would recommend you to learn WPF through its core concepts like DataTemplates and DataBinding as it provides you a more robust way of creating dynamic content. Let me know if you are still having problems

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works like a charm. I will have a look into DataTemplates and DataBinding. But one little question remains I want to direct to you. What exactly is the `shapes` object doing in your code, what is its task? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Pain shapes is the same collection as you have used in your old code. It will be useful if you want to keep track all the items that have been added to the canvas.